# One Bootstrap Modal affects the other

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have two bootstrap modals on a page. The first one (Modal_Add) will not work except if the second one (Modal_Edit) is first opened. *The text boxes will not be clickable and nothing can be typed*. But when I open the second one - without doing anything on it - and close, then open the first that was not working, it works. below are the codes

```
<!-- MODAL ADD -->
        <form id="add_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelA" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" >
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelB">Add New Member</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="container-fluid">
                          <input type="hidden" name="member_units" id="member_units" value="<?php if (isset($units_code)){echo $units_code;}?>" class="form-control">
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <label class="col-form-label">Entrance Fee</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span6">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <input type="text" name="entrance_amount" id="entrance_amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Entrance Fee">
                                  <span id="entrance_amount_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Member Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <input type="text" name="member_name" id="member_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"> <span id="member_name_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Address</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <input type="text" name="member_address" id="member_address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                              <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Member Phone</label>
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" maxlength="11" name="member_phone" id="member_phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                                <span id="member_phone_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Gender Status</label>
                                  <div class="col-md-8">
                                      <select name="gender_status" id="gender_status" class="form-control tooltips" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="choose a Gender Status" > 
                                        <option value="0">--select--</option>
                                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                                        <option value="company">Company</option>
                                        <option value="society">Society</option>
                                      </select>
                                      <span id="gender_status_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                              <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Banker</label>
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" name="banker" id="banker" class="form-control" placeholder="Banker">
                                <span id="banker_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                             <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Account Number</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <input type="text" name="accountno" id="accountno" class="form-control" placeholder="Account Number" maxlength="10">
                                  <span id="accountno_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label" id="g-label">Guarantors</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <select data-placeholder="Type Guarantors" name="guarantors[]" id="guarantors" class="chosen" multiple="multiple">
                                    <!-- <option value="0">A</option> -->
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span6">
                              <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Means of ID</label>
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" maxlength="11" name="id_means" id="id_means" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your NIN">
                                <span id="id_means_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                              <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Date Joined</label>
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="date" name="date_joined" id="date_joined" class="form-control datepicker" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Upload Passport</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' /> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="submit" id="btn_save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </form>
        <!--END MODAL ADD-->

  <!-- MODAL EDIT -->
        <form id="edit_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="modal fade" id="Modal_Edit" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelE" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelF">Edit Member</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                          <input type="hidden" name="member_units" id="member_units" value="<?php if (isset($units_code)){echo $units_code;}?>" class="form-control">
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Union Code</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                              <input type="hidden" name="member_code_edit" id="member_code_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Member Code" readonly>
                              <input type="text" name="union_code_edit" id="union_code_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Union Code" readonly>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Member Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <input type="text" name="member_name_edit" id="member_name_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"> 
                                  <span id="member_name_edit_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Address</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <input type="text" name="member_address_edit" id="member_address_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                              <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Member Phone</label>
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" maxlength="11" name="member_phone_edit" id="member_phone_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                                <span id="member_phone_edit_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="span6">
                              <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Means of ID</label>
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" maxlength="11" name="id_means_edit" id="id_means_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your NIN">
                                <span id="id_means_edit_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                              <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Banker</label>
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" name="banker_edit" id="banker_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Banker">
                                <span id="banker_edit_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                             <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Account Number</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <input type="text" name="accountno_edit" id="accountno_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Account Number" maxlength="10">
                                  <span id="accountno_edit_error" class="label label-important"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                              <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Date Joined</label>
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="date" name="date_joined_edit" id="date_joined_edit" class="form-control datepicker" value="" readonly="">
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Upload Passport</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input type='file' name='userfile_edit' size='20'/> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label" id="g-label">Current Guarantors</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div id="current_gurantors"></div>
                                    <!-- <option value="0">A</option> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span6">
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label" id="g-label">Guarantors</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <select data-placeholder="Type Guarantors" name="guarantors_edit[]" id="guarantors_edit" class="chosen" multiple="multiple">
                                    <!-- <option value="0">A</option> -->
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="btn_update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!--END MODAL EDIT-->
```

However, when i put the code for Modal_Edit on top of the code for Modal_Add, the problem affects Modal_Edit and vice versa

Edited

when I copied the code to https://www.codeply.com/p?starter=Bootstrap it works fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: can you add a working example.

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: do you get any error in console